# Customize 'at' with extra parameters for the closure?

Tags: geb

Is it possible to specify some optional parameter(s) to the 'at' closure on the page like this:

```
class ManagerDashboardClientsPage extends Page {
    static at = { year, geo ->
        if (year) {
            GebUtil.selectedYear == year
        }
        title.endsWith('Dashboard: Clients')
    }
}
```

so that I can write both

```
at ManagerDashboardClientsPage
```

and

```
at ManagerDashboardClientsPage(2013, 'North East')
```

Currently the first one breaks with

```
No signature of method: page.ManagerDashboardClientsPage$__clinit__closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: doCall(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), call(), call([Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.Object), call(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), equals(java.lang.Object)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: page.ManagerDashboardClientsPage$__clinit__closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: doCall(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), call(), call([Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.Object), call(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), equals(java.lang.Object)
    at geb.Page.verifyThisPageAtOnly(Page.groovy:165)
    at geb.Page.verifyAt(Page.groovy:133)
    at geb.Browser.doAt(Browser.groovy:358)
    at geb.Browser.at(Browser.groovy:289)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.methodMissing(GebSpec.groovy:51)
    at spec.ManagerDashboardClientsSpec.login as CEO(ManagerDashboardClientsSpec.groovy:16)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Groovy you can set default values for optional closure parameters, like so:

```
static at = { year=null, geo=null ->
    ...
}
```

I think that'll clear ya up. :)

**update**

Ok, I know you don't need it anymore, but I made this for my own use when I was learning Groovy, and I thought someone might find it helpful:

- `{ -> ... }` *a closure with exactly zero parameters. Groovy will blow up if you call it with params.*
- `{ ... }` *a closure with one optional parameter, named "it"*
- `{ foo -> ... }` *a closure with one parameter named "foo" (foo can be any type)*
- `{ foo, bar, baz -> ... }` *a closure with 3 parameters named "foo", "bar" and "baz"*
- `{ String foo -> ... }` *You can specify the type of the parameters if you like*