# Parametrize 'at' closure with arguments from script or spock specs

Tags: testing, groovy, spock, geb

There is similar question, but without answer 
[Customize 'at' with extra parameters for the closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740702/customize-at-with-extra-parameters-for-the-closure/23117269#23117269)

I want to reuse my page objects in different scenarios with different input and expected data. and since "at" method doesn't give me a way to extract expected data from other source like csv file i wonder what is the best practices to do it?

For example i have a scenario

```
def "Equity mew order creation scenario"() {
    given:
        to PortalPage
    when:
        navigateTo 'Equity Syndicate'
    then:
        at DealCalendarPage
```

and in DealCalendarPage

```
static at = {
    $('div', id: 'rightPane').find('tr').text() ==  'Equity Syndicate'
}
```

now if i want to reuse DealCalendarPage for another scenario i.e for structured products

```
def "SP mew order creation scenario"() {
    given:
        to PortalPage
    when:
        navigateTo 'Structured Products'
    then:
        at DealCalendarPage
```

i want to have

```
static at = {
    $('div', id: 'rightPane').find('tr').text() ==  'Structured products'
}
```

in DealCalendarPage

but i cannot parametrize my Page Object's "at" method

Or page object's 'at' method is not a good place to do such validation, and i have to do it explicitly in scenario?

Comment: your question is not clear? can you please elaborate?

Comment: i want something like static at = { paneCaption -> 
    $('div', id: 'rightPane').find('tr').text() ==  paneCaption
}